# Missing title displayed in plotly

Tags: python, layout, plotly

I am trying to change the background color in `plotly`, but after using layout function, I'm missing title from plotly.

```
layout = Layout(
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)
data['Country'].value_counts()[:10][::-1].iplot(kind="barh",bargap=.5, title="Top 10 countries faced terrorist attacks", colors="#182844", layout=layout)
```

[image]

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: @vestland I tried adding layout the the iplot itself and it worked. We can also adjust margin along with it.

Comment: Sample Code: 
`data['Region'].value_counts()[1:10][::-1].iplot(kind="barh",bargap=.5, title="Top 10 cities faced terrorist attacks", 
                                                colors="mediumorchid", layout=Layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                                                                                plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                                                                                width=800, height=500, 
                                                                                title='Top 10 Region faced terrorist attacks'))`

Comment: Cool! Please consider wrting that as an answer instead of a comment!

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better off using `go.Figure()` instead of `iplot()`. It's hard to make out what the problem is with your plot, but with an example from [plot.ly/python/horizontal-bar-charts/](https://plot.ly/python/horizontal-bar-charts/) you can easily set both title and background color using `fig.update_layout()`

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
            x=[20, 14, 23],
            y=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            orientation='h'))

fig.update_layout(title='Title',
                 paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                 plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding layout the the iplot itself and it worked. We can also adjust margin along with it.

Sample Code:

```
data['Nationality'].value_counts()[0:10][::-1].iplot(kind="barh",bargap=.5, 
                                                colors="mediumorchid", layout=Layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                                                                             plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                                                                                width=800, height=500, 
                                                                                title='Nationality of terrorist attacks',
                                                                                margin=dict(l=200, r=50, t=80, b=50)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1fID.png)